# Repeating Field vs Relational?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a set of data. It's a group of houses in certain cities.

```
House 1 | 123 Fake St | Notatown
House 2 | 456 Not Rd  | Notatown
House 3 | 789 Foo Cres| Barville
...
```

Then imagine that the data went on like this with many records.

Is it better to import this directly into a table, having a record for each house, and putting the town in full - or to create a relational table that stores an id along with the town's name and have to play with inserting into multiple tables? Ie:

```
1 | Notatown
2 | Barville
...
```

What "Normal Form" would doing the relational table above be considered, if so?

Comment: Can you have 1 house in multiple towns? I don't think so.

Comment: That depends of your application requirements. If there are other entities that are referring to cities, it will be important to store them at one table, so you will change your city storage once. If you have only one place, where you're using cities entity, you can place it directly in main table

Comment: Replacing text with an ID number has nothing to do with normalization. That doesn't mean you shouldn't do it. It just means you shouldn't call it *normalization*. Making that change--substituting ID numbers for text--won't change the normal form. If your table is in 3NF before that change, it will be in 3NF after that change.

Answer (score 0):

The version with the town name directly in the houses table could be considered the second normal form (2NF), because the transient relation of town hasn't been moved to its own table.

Whether or not you need to refactor this to the third normal form really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on what you are going to do with the data.

In general, storing the town name in the address field is not a horrible sin.  You are correct that the more normalized storage would be to have a separate "city" table, with keys to look up the city values.  Such a structure is more important when the data is going to be updated.  For static data (and city names don't change very much), it is less important.

The advantages of keeping the town name in one table are readability for people and for less technical users who can just download the address table.

The advantages of moving the town name to another tables are consistency, updatability, and the preservation of ACID requirements for databases (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability).  In addition, if the city names tend to exceed four characters, the normalized version will probably save space.  (The latter is not true on a columnar database that compresses column values.)

In *both* cases, you need to be sensitive to alternative spellings for places.  If you have a master list of towns, then use that and highlight the values that don't match.  This also assumes that "town" is not central to your business.  Having a separate table for, say, customer names is very important, because you do not want misspellings to result in overcounting customers.